# Swagger UI - Rendering nested object in multipart/form-data request "try it out" shows JSON instead of form UI fields

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

I am using Swagger/OpenAPI version: OpenAPI 3.0.3

Example Swagger/OpenAPI definition:

```
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
    title: 'My API'
    version: 3.0.0
servers: []
paths:
    /api_app:
        post:
            operationId: apiAppCreate
            requestBody:
                content:
                    multipart/form-data:
                        schema:
                            $ref: '#/components/schemas/ApiAppCreateRequest'
            responses:
                '200':
                    description: 'success'
                    content:
                        application/json:
                            schema: {}
components:
    schemas:
        ApiAppCreateRequest:
            properties:
                oauth:
                  type: object
                  properties:
                      callback_url:
                          type: string
                          example: 'https://example.com/oauth'
                      scopes:
                          type: array
                          items:
                              type: string
                          example:
                              - basic_account_info
                              - request_signature
            type: object
```

The nested object displays as Json input instead of form-data as shown in attached image.

[image: Swagger ui]

It should be rendered as form-fields. This happens only when we have form-data or multipart/form-data type of request and it has a nested object within.

Seems no solution on github issues of swagger ui so thought of asking on stackoverflow if in case anyone able to resolve this issue.

I am using Java 8 with dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springdoc/springdoc-openapi-ui -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Another example of how the UI renders partly in form-data and partly as json input

[image: swagger ui issue]

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

I'm not sure what exactly `oauth` is being used as, but it seems like this is a request for an oauth token.  The issue you are facing is due to your schema declaration, where you are declaring everything as a property of `oauth`.  The `type: object` forces everything into a json schema, and by declaring everything as a property of `oauth`, it's forcing it into the `oauth` schema as a json object.

```yaml
properties:
  oauth:
    type: object
    properties:
```

You can fix this two ways.

### Solution 1

remove the top level properties value and reduce the indentation of the `callback_url` and `scopes`.

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    ApiAppCreateRequest:
      properties:
        oath:
          type: object
        callback_url:
          type: string
          example: 'https://example.com/oauth'
        scopes:
          type: array
          items:
            type: string
          example:
            - basic_account_info
            - request_signature
      type: object
```

This will result in the following display in your try it out
[image: With oauth property]

### Solution 2

Remove the `oauth` entirely.

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    ApiAppCreateRequest:
      properties:
        callback_url:
          type: string
          example: 'https://example.com/oauth'
        scopes:
          type: array
          items:
            type: string
          example:
            - basic_account_info
            - request_signature
      type: object
```

This will remove the json object for oauth completely, as the below screenshot demonstrates.
[image: without oauth property]

### Alternatives

Depending on what you are trying to do with the `oauth` property, you could also restructure what the property is, such as a file or a security schema:

#### As a file

As a file, simply update the schema to have a `type: string` and `format: binary`.  This will allow the user to upload a file to be used as the security authorization.

```yaml
oauth:
  type: string
  format: binary
```

#### As security schema

You can also include the oauth as the security schema separately as a part of the request.

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
    title: 'My API'
    version: 3.0.0
servers: []
paths:
  /api_app:
    post:
      operationId: apiAppCreate
      requestBody:
          content:
            multipart/form-data:
              schema:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/ApiAppCreateRequest'
      security:
        - oAuthSample:
          - create_app
      responses:
        '200':
          description: 'success'
          content:
            application/json:
              schema: {}
components:
  schemas:
    ApiAppCreateRequest:
      properties:
        callback_url:
          type: string
          example: 'https://example.com/oauth'
        scopes:
          type: array
          items:
            type: string
          example:
            - basic_account_info
            - request_signature
      type: object
  securitySchemes:
    oAuthSample:
      type: oauth2
      description: This API uses OAuth 2 with the implicit grant flow. [More info](https://whatever.com)
      flows:
        implicit:
          authorizationUrl: https://whatever.com
          scopes:
            create_app: create a new app
```

### Finally

The `multipart/form-data` content type has a lot of possibilities.  You can check the [swagger documentation](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/multipart-requests/) or the [openapi documentation](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.1.0#special-considerations-for-multipart-content) for more information.  For example, you can use [the `encoding` property](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.1.0#encoding-object) to gain control over the way in which various parts of the request bodies are serialized.  This includes setting the headers, `explode`, and `style`.

Comment: its not only about the oauth thing, Its about averall behaviour of the swagger-ui as to how it is rendering partly things as form data and partly as json input.
The expected behaviour is to render everything as form-data instead of any json input in the swagger-ui.

Like check the second screenshot in the question please. You will then get a clear picture

Comment: Yes, I addressed this. It's not about `oauth`, it's about the way you declare your object types. The provided solutions address any issue, regardless of the property name (oauth or something else).  The main point here is that if you declare something as a `type: object`, then it will be treated as an object (i.e. json). Anything that you put as a child of the `type: object` will be treated as a child of the json object. In your schema, you declared oauth as a `type: object` this creates a json because that's the shape of the object you declared.

Comment: Then am wondering how to structure nested objects in our Java models as those will ofcourse have `object` type and is quite common.
Cant ofcourse declare all fields always at root level